# With Clause List

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

**Aim**: I would like to use a With Clause to select ***a list*** of countries. The following works for selecting only **one** country.

```
WITH parameters AS (SELECT 'Sweden' as Country) 
SELECT * 
FROM Countries_table 
WHERE Countries_table.Country = (SELECT Country FROM parameters)
```

I would like to do the same but to use a list of countries in the with-clause.
I have attempted syntax like (but neither works):

```
WITH parameters AS (SELECT ('Sweden', 'Norway', 'Finland') as Country)
SELECT * 
FROM Countries_table 
WHERE Countries_table.Country IN (SELECT Country FROM parameters)
```

and...

```
WITH parameters AS (SELECT ['Sweden', 'Norway', 'Finland'] as Country)
SELECT * 
FROM Countries_table 
WHERE Countries_table.Country IN (SELECT Country FROM parameters)
```

What would the proper syntax be to achieve a list in with-clause, and pass that list to the following select statement?

The results should look like this for each country in the list:

```
Country |    Town     | Population size
---------------------------------------
Sweden | Stockholm | 1 500 000
```

Comment: I'm really confused.  Your code has no window functions.

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve? It would help make the question clearer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, my bad. It is not a window function. I will update language.

Comment: `where country in ('a', 'b', 'c', etc) `?

Comment: @MatBailie - I think thats the procedure I want to avoid. The reason is that the code I work on is long, and I want to use parameters in order to update in all locations at once (more convient and reduces risk of manual error) :)

Comment: `With list as (select 'a' UNION ALL select 'b' UNION ALL....)` or insert in to holding/staging tables

Comment: Or `with list as (select * from countries where name in (normal list))`

Comment: @MatBailie That works! If you would post it as an answer I would accept be able to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres you could do:

```
WITH parameters (country) AS (
  values ('Sweden'), ('Norway'), ('Finland')
)
SELECT * 
FROM Countries_table 
WHERE Countries_table.Country IN (SELECT Country FROM parameters);
```

If Redshift doesn't support that, you need to use a `UNION`

```
WITH parameters (country) AS (
  select 'Sweden' union all
  select 'Norway' union all
  select 'Finland'
)
SELECT * 
FROM Countries_table 
WHERE Countries_table.Country IN (SELECT Country FROM parameters);
```